# How to append row value to the other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table that includes two columns:

| P_SEG | SEG_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [2, 4] |
| 2 | [4, 3,5] |

I want to create a new column that includes the 1st column value in the second column list as follows,

| P_SEG | SEG_ID | New Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [2, 4] | [1, 2, 4] |

Comment: Please state the language and library you are using within the body of the question, and not just as a tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can try apply on rows or add the two columns:

```py
df['New Column'] = df.apply(lambda row: [row['P_SEG']]+row['SEG_ID'], axis=1)

# or

df['New Column'] = df['P_SEG'].apply(lambda x: [x]) + df['SEG_ID']
```

```
print(df)

   P_SEG     SEG_ID    New Column
0      1     [2, 4]     [1, 2, 4]
1      2  [4, 3, 5]  [2, 4, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join lists with scalar in list comprehension:

```
df['New Column'] = [[y, *x] for x, y in zip(df['SEG_ID'], df['P_SEG'])]
print (df)
   P_SEG     SEG_ID    New Column
0      1     [2, 4]     [1, 2, 4]
1      2  [4, 3, 5]  [2, 4, 3, 5]
```